# Highlight specific item in treetableview or treeview

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-tableview

I have two TreeViews/TreeTableViews. When clicking on a specific TreeItem in one of those Trees I first collapse the other Tree and then expand only the path to the Item that holds the same information. This is already working nicely.

What is missing still: When expanding the second path of the second Tree I would like Highlight the TreeItem in the second Tree that hold the same information for a shot time( a second or so).

I tried to set it selected and played around setStyle function, which did not have any effect.

Could you give me a hint how to solve this?

Thanks in advance